# How to move Javascript functions within object and DRY?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, javascript-objects, dom-events

In functions presented below are repeated the same operations. I'd like to move as much as possible to the object. Maybe it is possible directly from button once initialize right method in object?

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<button onclick="drawPoly()">Draw This Poly</button>
<button onclick="newPoly()">Create New Poly</button>
<button onclick="restorePolys()">Restore Polys</button>
<button onclick="dropMarker()">Drop Marker</button>
```

JS:

```
var map;
var mapListener = null;

$(function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.864715, 10.546875),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
});

dropMarker = function() {
    if ( !! mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(mapListener);

    mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        tools.createMarker(e.latLng);
    });
}

drawPolyline = function() {
    if ( !! mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(mapListener);

    mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        tools.addPoint(e.latLng);
    });
}

newPolyline = function() {
    if ( !! mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(mapListener);

    tools.createPolyline();
    mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        tools.addPoint(e.latLng);
    });
}

newPolygon = function() {
    if ( !! mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(mapListener);

    tools.createPolygon();
    mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        tools.addPoint(e.latLng);
    });
}

var tools = {
    polyMarkers: [],
    polyLines: [],
    polyLine: null,
    // ...

    // mapListener: null,
    // tools: function(option) {
    //     if ( !! this.mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(this.mapListener);
    //     this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    //         option(e.latLng);
    //     });
    // },
    // and so on
```

**EDIT** I got expected function, added to tools:

```
mapListener: null,

initFeature: function(type, aspect) {
    if ( !! this.mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(this.mapListener);

    if (aspect) this[aspect]();

    this.mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        tools[type](e.latLng);
    });
},
```

Call:

```
tools.initFeature(type, aspect);
```

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking

Comment: I can. All his functions look the same, except for the line `tools.DO_SOMETHING(e.latLng);` How can he condense this into a single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you are trying to do maybe having a builder function will help, something like this that should handle most of your case usage.

```
function MakeNew(act1, act2) {

    return function() {

        if ( !! mapListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(mapListener);

        if ( act2 ) tools[act2]();

        mapListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            tools[act1](e.latLng);
        });
    };
};


dropMarker = MakeNew('createMarker');
newPolygon = MakeNew('addPoint', 'createPolygon');
createPolygon = MakeNew('addPoint', 'createPolyline');
```

Comment: Maybe you could even pass Google's methods as a reference to the closure - then you don't need to quarrel with a string and the array-like object index. That would probably be an atomic little bit better: `createMarker = MakeNew(tools.createMarker);` and call it via `act1(e.latLng)`

Comment: U implemented "Aspect-oriented programming" in js :)

Comment: Ok looks fine but I mean whether in `tools` object is possibility to make initialize function that chose after clicked button right other method in the same `tools`.

Comment: I didn't know that I entered to the areas of "Aspect-oriented programming". Thanks.